# LogParser URLUNESCAPE '+'

Tags: urldecode, logparser

Is there any way to get LogParser (2.2) URLUNESCAPE function to decode a '+' as a ' '(space)?

```
logparser "select URLUNESCAPE('test+value') into stdout from system"
```

produces the following output

```
'test+value'
------------
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
test+value
Press a key...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, as the `+` <-> `<space>` replacement is technically not URL escaping (while `%20` <-> `<space>` is). For this task you might want to consider using `REPLACE_CHR` as:

```
REPLACE_CHR('test+value', '+', ' ')
```